# Can't find title of Korean Movie, sci fi/fantasy, hero runs up side of building

Tags: story-identification, movie

Trying to find a Korean live-action, sci-fi/fantasy/futuristic movie from early 2000s that featured a hero who wears a white super hero suit with a half mask. Several anime style shots like the hero runs up or down the side of a building. And a scene were he cuts through a tank, splits it in half. There is a big army moving down a street in a dark city in the future. And finishes where he fights a villain on the top of a tank.

I feel like the movie title was one word that started with an "C". Something like "Caspian". Anyone recognize this one?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Was the movie dubbed or subtitled?  Can you remember anything about the villain or the plot the hero was trying to foil?

Comment: @David Graham - When you say the hero wore a "half mask", which part/s of the face did it cover?

Comment: Subtitled, Korean. Plot I'm unsure as that's the reason I wanted to revisit it. Partially involves saving a women he loves. A grand villian to fight. The mask was white like a subzero mask. The white suit was like a tight fighting action outfit. Lots of anime style fighting, but live action.

Comment: Bottom part, the mouth and part of nose.

Comment: There was heavy rock music in background of action sequences.

Comment: There's a scene in the end with a big army and tanks moving through a dark city in the future.

Comment: Movie was called something like "Caspian"

Comment: Nothing seems particularly relevant in [this IMDb query](https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?title_type=feature&release_date=1990-01-01,2017-12-31&genres=sci-fi&countries=kr&sort=release_date,asc), but still, take a look just in case...

Comment: Got it! Casshern!!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***[Casshern](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0405821/)*** (2004).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casshern_(film)):

> *Casshern* (キャシャーン, Kyashān) is a 2004 Japanese tokusatsu superhero film adaptation of the [anime series of the same name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casshan). It was written and directed by Kazuaki Kiriya. It is one of only a few films (*Sky Captain and the World of Tomorrow* (2004) and *Sin City* (2005), among others) to be shot entirely on a "digital backlot".

This was a very hard one to find. Thanks everyone for helping!